# Setup SonarQube 8.7 Developer with Github integration

Tags: github, sonarqube

[o.s.s.a.AuthenticationError] No provider key found in URI

This is the error I am getting inside my fargate container. I followed the instructions that sonarqube provides [here](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/github-integration/)

I keep getting a "Not authorized page"

Comment: As per the self-answer, this should be close as not reproducible / caused by a typo.

Answer (score 0):

When adding the callback URL in GitHub lots of people said they had to add /oauth2/callback at the end of the URL. I discovered in my case this was wrong and once I removed that it worked just fine.